# importing Excel

Tags: .net, excel

I am looking to import some part of an Excel 2010 worksheet into a SQL Server 2005.  What's the best of way of doing it, .Net command line script, a VBA script, need a little help here.

Also, I need to iterate through the excel rows and import only some of them - the non-duplicates.

So, don't be shy and give me all the relevant info - references, connection strings, etc... 
I've been away from programming for a while, so don't worry about being overly verbose :)

Thaks,
Mike

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of potential solutions - which one is relevant will depend on your specific context, about which you've given next to no information.

1. If the volume of data is low, you are targeting a single table, and this is single shot, use Excel formulas to generate SQL to run directly against the database using SQL Server Management Studio.
2. If the volume of data is high and/or there are multiple tables, but this is still single shot, use SSIS to copy the data across.

   - You can access Excel files through an ODBC driver from SSIS
   - SSIS is licensed as a part of SQL Server 2005
3. If the volume of data is low, and you need this to work across a limited number of environments that are all under your control, use [COM Interop to drive Excel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) by remote control and read the data.
4. If you're creating some kind of product, a third partly tool like [SyncFusion XlsIo](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/reporting-edition/xlsio) will eliminate most of the likely failure modes.

Comment: Hi Bevan, thanks for your answer.  I am intrigued by #1, how would you actually do it?